# Find the binary equivalent of integer in Java using a while loop

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I've been writing code to find the binary equivalent of an integer in Java using a while loop. I've written the following code and it's not throwing any error, but it was not printing **INVALID INPUT**. It is printing the valid binary number of a given integer value. Can anyone suggest where and what I'm doing wrong? And how should I get the proper input?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        if ((n >= 0) && n > 999) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        } else {
            while (n > 1) {
                if (n <= 999) {
                    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: Change `&&` to `||`.

Comment: Look carefully at the condition: `if (!(n >= 0) && n > 999)`: "if not n is greater or equal to zero AND n greater than 999". This can never be true; n cannot be less than zero and greater than 999 at the same time.

Comment: Also, your `while` loop will run forever if n is greater than 1 and less than or equal to 999.

Answer (score 2):

Change `&&` to `||`:

```
if (!(n >= 0) || n > 999) {
```

Or even better, express conditions without negation:

```
if (n < 0 || n > 999) {
```

Positive conditions, ie "a *is* b", are easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a loop at all?  You're just adding needless complexity.  Your code can be re-written to this:

```
if (n >= 0 && n < 1000) {
   System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
   return;
}
    
System.out.println("Invalid Input");
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said if this is an assignment but typically it is done like this for such questions.

- loop until value is 0
- get remainder from division by `2`.
- prepend to string
- divide `n` by `2` to expose next binary digit.

```
// get some input,
int n = 1249;
String s = "";
while(n != 0) {
  s = (n%2) + s;
  n/=2;
}
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
10011100001
```